# Prevent gridview from losing focus if validation fails

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, telerik

I have a Telerik radGridView on a form which has cell and row validation implemented. No problem with that, works well.

The problem arises when I leave a row incomplete and then click on the Save button elsewhere on the form. The RowValidating code snippet below does not work, because once the focus moves away from the gridview to the Save button, the if (row != null) is always false, and the RowValidating code is never executed.

```
 private void radGridView1_RowValidating(object sender, RowValidatingEventArgs e)
    {
        var row = e.Row as GridViewDataRowInfo;

        if (row != null)
        {
            var value = row.Cells["cboUnit"].Value.ToString();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                row.ErrorText = "Unit Number is a required field";
            }

            else
            {
                row.ErrorText = string.Empty;
            }
```

How can I retain focus in the grid to ensure that he entire grid validates before allowing the user to leave the grid and save?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Telerik controls, but I know the standard `DataGridView` only fires the `RowValidating` event when the `CurrentRow` changes. If the grid in its entirety is losing focus but the `CurrentRow` remains the same, I believe you have to trigger validation yourself (such as calling the `Form.ValidateChildren()` method).

Comment: I will try alternate methods to trigger the validation - Form.ValidateChilden() returns true no matter what the condition of the grid is.

Comment: You could also try `Form.Validate()`. If all else fails you can always try to set `grid.CurrentCell = null` which should throw an `InvalidOperationException`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try giving both the conditions together.

```
private void radGridView1_RowValidating(object sender, RowValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    var row = e.Row as GridViewDataRowInfo;        
        var value = row.Cells["cboUnit"].Value.ToString();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) && row != null)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            row.ErrorText = "Unit Number is a required field";
        }

        else
        {
            row.ErrorText = string.Empty;
        }
```

I haven't tried the codes but hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. But the problem with this approach is that the code fails at if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)...) if value == null

Comment: @PeterJ So please give Or operator instead of AND(&&). here I have And operator.Instead of that give || so that it checks for both the condition and if ANY of them is fails it it will still work.

Comment: The problem is, when the row == null returns true, the string.IsNullOrEmpty is automatically also true, so the code is never executed. I think I may be overlooking something silly here, but after two days of trying almost every imaginable permutation of options, I am still stuck!